# How to resolve this query?

Tags: mysql

I need to sum all the values of this query before the output, i do not know how

This is the query:

```
SELECT u.usuario, u.id_usuario, d.id, COUNT(v.valoracion) AS votos, COUNT(d.id) * 4 AS dibujos, COUNT(c.id) AS comentarios
FROM icar_dibujos d
LEFT JOIN icar_valoraciones v ON d.id = v.id_dibujo
LEFT JOIN icar_usuarios u ON d.id_quien = u.id_usuario
LEFT JOIN icar_comentarios c ON u.id_usuario GROUP BY d.id_quien
```

What i want is to output the sum of votos + dibujos + comentarios

How can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: LOL, i don't know how i didn't saw that! Thanks! Add it as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply sum the counts:

```
SELECT u.usuario, u.id_usuario, d.id, COUNT(v.valoracion) AS votos, COUNT(d.id) * 4 AS dibujos, COUNT(c.id) AS comentarios, COUNT(v.valoracion) + COUNT(d.id) * 4 + COUNT(c.id) AS TotalSum
FROM icar_dibujos d
LEFT JOIN icar_valoraciones v ON d.id = v.id_dibujo
LEFT JOIN icar_usuarios u ON d.id_quien = u.id_usuario
LEFT JOIN icar_comentarios c ON u.id_usuario GROUP BY d.id_quien
```